# Maui appiconfg not appearing

Tags: c#, maui, maui-android

I'm trying to set the app icon for my maui app. Specifically working with android. My "appicon" is just a plain white svg while "appiconfg" has the actual app design.

Whenever I run the app, the app icon appears just plain white. Like appicon is being placed on top of appiconfg or as if appiconfg is not there at all.
Same with the splash screen.
[Screenshot of icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZpdt.png)

I have this in my project file:

```
<!-- App Icon -->
<MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" Foreground="Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg" />

<!-- Splash Screen -->      
<MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\appicon.svg" Foreground="Resources\Splash\appiconfg.svg" />
```

And have set the application icon to '@mipmap/appicon' in the android manifest.
Ive double checked that both files are in Resources\AppIcon

Comment: What is this "MauiAppIcon" tag? I have MauiIcon instead. Is this something new? More important - how did you lose the icon at first place? I mean, the template comes with icon, and all you have to do is replace it.

Comment: Typo. Edited to MauiIcon.  Which I did replace the existing icon files. I just modified appicon to be white instead of purple and replaced ".NET" with a different design. Then just added them back to the AppIcon folder.

Comment: Make a new template project, do not modify the manifest, nor the project file. Replace the svg files with the ones you have. If do not see them - it may be a problem with the files themselves.

Comment: So the SVGs worked fine in a new project. I ended up adding a Color and ForegroundScale to the MauiIcon in my original project and that fixed it. <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg"  ForegroundScale="0.70" Color="#512BD4" />

Answer (score 0):

So the SVGs worked fine in a new project. I ended up adding a Color and ForegroundScale to the MauiIcon in my original project and that fixed it.

```
<MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg" ForegroundScale="0.70" Color="#512BD4" />
```